# TYPO3 radio button validation best practice

Tags: validation, radio-button, fluid, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I have a simple fluid form with radio and normal input fields like this:

```
<f:form action="create" name="data" object="{data}">
    <p>Wählen Sie Ihre Schulform aus:</p>
    <f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{field: 'data.schoolType'}" />
    <f:form.radio id="secondary-school" property="schoolType" value="secondary-school" />
    <label for="secondary-school">Gymnasium</label>
    <f:form.radio id="school" property="schoolType" value="school" />
    <label for="school">Oberschule</label>

    <label for="name">
        <f:translate key="tx_example_domain_model_school.name" />
        <span class="required">*</span>
        <f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{field: 'data.name'}"/>
    </label>
    <f:form.textfield property="name" />

    ...

</f:form>
```

Now I want to validate the radio buttons, because both are initial not checked, but I don't know if the way that I have used is a good one.

I am working with properties like the example above shows and have created the following class:

```
class Data extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * schoolType
     * 
     * @var string
     * @validate \Example\Example\Domain\Validator\CustomValidator
     */
    protected $schoolType;

    /**
     * name
     * 
     * @var string
     * @validate NotEmpty
     */
    protected $name;

    irrelvant properties, setter, getter and so on ...
}
```

So I have used a custom validator to validate the radio buttons, which looks as follows:

```
class CustomValidator extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\AbstractValidator {

     protected $acceptsEmptyValues = FALSE;

     /**
      * Validates the radio buttons
      *
      * @param mixed $value
      * @return bool
      */
     public function isValid($value) {
         if ( !isset($value) || $value === NULL ) {
             $this->addError( 'Wählen Sie einen Schultyp aus.', time() );
             return FALSE;
         }
         return TRUE;
     }
 }
```

It works as expected, but is there no easier way to get the same solution? Maybe  using a standard TYPO3 validator? I have used a property of type string for the radio buttons, because I am working with the values of this radio buttons and store it as strings.

Suggestions and comments are welcome :)

Comment: So why don't you use NotEmpty Validator? What do you focus on, a custom error message or a preselection of your radio buttons?

Comment: You are right, NotEmpty Validator works too and I can throw a custom error message by using fluid translate and the error code, so I don't need a custom validator :)

Comment: Yes, you can, but as far as I know you can only change the translation of the NotEmptyValidator globally. This is still a feature I miss in Extbase, to set an individual error message on a default extbase validator. Therefore I'd still prefer your solution to create a custom validator.

Comment: You can also use the errorcode and translation file for custom error messages in association with standard validators, for example (property name has NotEmpty Validator): 

fluid layout:
<f:render partial="FormErrors" arguments="{field: 'data.name'}"/>
<f:form.textfield property="name" />

error partial: 
<f:translate key="{field}.{error.code}">{error.message}</f:translate>

locallang.xlf
<trans-unit id="data.name.1221560718">
    <source>enter name please</source>
</trans-unit>

so you can easily customize the standard error messages for each field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think NotEmpty Validator in combination with language file is the a acceptable solution